# Stream contents of a single window

Tags: windows, video, streaming, vlc-media-player

I've been using VLC to stream my desktop over the network and it's great. However, I would like to stream only the contents of a specific window (like Alt + PrintScren works for screenshots).

Is there some way to do this on Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to specify the window coordinates + width and height.

[VLC Command Line](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) : Screen Input section

Capture 640x480 pixels in the top left corner:

```
 "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --screen-width=640 --screen-height=480
```

Comment: This is a gread idea, though it requires some manual work (getting the window position and dimensions)! For some reason it won't work with global options but I got it to work with MRL specific options: `"c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" screen:// :screen-top=150 :screen-left=150 :screen-width=300 :screen-height=200`